# Indenting org entries programmatically

Tags: org-mode, indentation

If I have a bunch of headings with sub-headings and content, how can I programmatically indent them correctly? I've tried combining bunch of elisp functions with [mapping api](http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-mapping-API.html), still can't figure it out.

Comment: Is `org-indent-mode` what you're looking for? You can turn it on by setting `org-startup-indented` to `t`.

Comment: No, that's not it. The entries being created not by hand - by third-party automation, and that thing unfortunately ignores indentation completely. Org recognizes headings but won't fix the indentation, I have to manually fix every item, which becoming tedious.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you start with, and what you want? It's a bit confusing, because org-mode just indents headings properly on its own.

Comment: @zck in normal org heading does it content have to be prefixed with white-spaces or not? When I add a drawer or a property it automatically gets prefixed with two white-spaces. But since my content is not being created "by hand" white-spaces get omitted, rendering the content not properly indented.

Comment: @Agzam I don't see whitespace, before the body of an org headline, but again I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Can you edit into your question what you're getting from whatever non-Emacs tool generates your org file, and what you think Org requires?